# How can I say "can" in the future form?

Tags: tense, modal-verbs

If someone wants to say me that he can not do something in the next week but just after this next week. What is the way on English to say that?

> I will not can do that

or simply

> I can not do that next week

Is there no form for the future like many other languages?

Comment: Sorry, but the idea re the future is very simple: I will not be able to do that.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There is no such way of casting any of the modal verbs *can/could, may/might, must, shall/should, will/would* in future form with *will*.

This is because the modal verbs are all *defective*: they have only two forms, past and present (*must* has only one), so they lack the infinitive form which follows auxiliary will.

There are two ways around this.

1. The simple present of most verbs can be used with future reference, so one thing you can do is simply use *can* with some indication of futurity.

   > I cannot do that tomorrow.
   >   I may do that tomorrow.
2. The other thing you can do is employ the infinitive of a "periphrastic" construction as the complement of *will*. With *can*, for instance, the periphrastic construction is *BE able to*; with *will* it's *BE going to*.

   > I will not **be able to** do that.
   >   I will **be going to** do that.

   Other periphrastics which come in handy for this are:

   > for *may/might*: *be permitted/allowed to*: He will be permitted to do that.
   >   for *must*: *be obliged/required to*: He will be obliged to do that.
   >   for *should*: *be expected to*: He will be expected to do that.
   >   for *will*: *be going to*: He will be going to do that.

   There are more, because all the modals have a wide variety of meanings, and many of these meanings have one or more periphrastics.

Note that the modal verbs have no participles either, so they can't be cast in the perfect construction or employed as gerunds or adjectives. Again, the way around this is to employ the appropriate periphrastic:

> I have been able to do that.
>   Being able to do that would be helpful.

Modal verbs are intransitive and can't be cast in the passive, and they're stative and therefore can't be cast in the progressive, so you don't have to worry about those forms.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The real option is to use in the structure of: "He will not be able to do that in the next week". This is the best way for me to express what . Thank you.

Comment: @Assiduous Note that ***in the** next week* is not the same thing as *next week*. "I can do that next week" means during the seven days starting next Sunday or Monday. "I can do that in the next week" means during the seven days starting today.

Comment: Also, (although this example is not responsive to "cannot/not able), did you mean "will be going to do that", or " will **not** be going to do that"?  It seems odd that he will be doing it, even though he will not be able!  (But otherwise, great explanation!)

Answer (score 0):

For me, 'could' is a more logical future tense of 'can', because 'will be able to' is the future tense of 'can' when we talk about ability. So when we talk about possibility, we have to use 'could' to express 'can' in the future.