What's the difference bewteen these two expressions in meaning in this context?
A: What should I do in Taipei?
B: Well, it’s our national day this weekend. If you go shopping in the East District tomorrow, you will be able to/can join the parade with the locals.
What’s the difference between “can” and “will be able to” in meaning in the last sentence? Which one fits better?

You have asked umpteen questions about the difference between you can and you will be able to. I don't know what more you expect people to say about it.

One of the things I find curious about this insistence is how it presents the two options as equal peers. "Will be able to" would not be nearly as idiomatic in this example. It would be a better choice when the "if" clause changes your "ability."

@AndyBonner Which one do you think it's better? I think "can" present the available options that are choosable better than "will be able to," which focuses more on the gaining of ability.

Is it really unclear? The example you’ve given has nothing to do with gaining an ability. “Can” is the only idiomatic choice here. “Will be able to” is for things like “if you drink this magic potion you will be able to fly.”

Answered, or at least discussed, in https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/69865/how-can-i-say-can-in-the-future-form
